# Checking if div is already added/open before prepend?

Tags: jquery

I trying to build a menu/content solution where you click on a menu-link which adds a new div to the main content and loads it with a child html. Im using the .prepend so the newly opened content loads at the top of the div pushing the other content further down.

```
    $('#testappend').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#maincontent').prepend( "<div id='testcontent1' style='display: none; float:left; padding:15px; width:100%;'></div>" );
        $('#testcontent1').load("testhtml");
        $('#testcontent1').show();
```

But if I click the same link many times i don't want it to stack the same div many times so i need some method to check if the div is already loaded and maybe scroll to that one/or place it at the top again. I'm still new with jquery and I'm thinking doing it with a variable (boolean?). Or is it a better way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Three different ideas for you, each should work now that I've edited one of them:

```
if ($("#myDivID").load()) {
  run the code you want to run after the element has been loaded
}
```

edit:  better yet:

```
if ($("#myDivID").length) {
  return;
}
```

or a variation of the .length one:

```
if (!$("#myDivID").length) {
  run the code you want to run after the element has been loaded
}
```

Comment: on second thought... I need to think about this a minute longer... however the jQuery .load() method is definitely the ideal choice as it fires when the event is loaded.  update:  yea I reworked my code ideas a bit...  each should work in their own way, depends what's best for your needs.

Comment: the .load was misused in my example but you could work it differently since it fires when the event loads... see my new edit

Answer (score 1):

You can check the `$('#testcontent1').length` before you prepend. If it equals `0` it means that the element isn't in the DOM yet, otherwise it already exists.

And you can write everthing in a more compact way like that:

```
$('#testappend').click(function(event){
     event.preventDefault();
     if($('#testcontent1').length === 0)
         $("<div id='testcontent1' style='display: none; float:left; padding:15px; width:100%;'></div>")
            .prependTo('#maincontent')
            .load('testhtml')
            .show();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I might do something like

```
var $el;
$('#testappend').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (!$el) {
        $el = $("<div id='testcontent1' style='display: none; float:left; padding:15px; width:100%;'></div>").prependTo('#maincontent');
    }
    $el.load("testhtml", function () {
        $el.show();
    });
})
```

A cache variable is used here to check whether it is already created.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Im trying this one now. Just wondering, what does "el" stand for? Or is just a random variable name? And does the varibale have to stand outside the function in order to work?

Comment: @user3199840 it is just any variable name.... if you keep the variable inside the click handler it will get initialized every time the handler is called it resets the value which will result in we loosing the info that the element was already created

Comment: Ok. Aha i think get it. But say i want a close button (X) on the div also. Then it would have to change this variable back again to something (?). Im not sure what it's value is here. It's not true/false but the div iself? It's a little confusing for me as a beginner on this.

Comment: you can set `$el = undefined` once the element is deleted